# How can Chrome not automatically switch to new tab, when new tab is created?

Tags: google-chrome

I want stay on  current tab, like when I use Gleam [on IE](https://superuser.com/q/1470563/1022717). Has Chrome not added option to disable automatic switching to new tab? Are the forum posts under correct? [This Reddit post](https://redd.it/aw62vt) no help.

[How can I stop Chrome from auto switching to new tabs? : chrome](https://old.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/8nqksr/how_can_i_stop_chrome_from_auto_switching_to_new/)

> Unfortunately, middle click, right click + open new tab, and Ctrl-click don't always work - if the link also triggers something on the site or the site restricts alternate clicks then; middle, right, and Ctrl-clicks don't work.

[[Chrome] How do I stop Chrome from auto switching to new tabs? - Programs, Apps and Websites - Linus Tech Tips](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/933745-chrome-how-do-i-stop-chrome-from-auto-switching-to-new-tabs/?tab=comments#comment-11406342)

> Posted June 3, 2018
>
> [Gleam](https://gleam.io/ikYyW/steam-example-competition) is one main site that springs to mind - middle and right clicking are disabled.

[How to disable auto-switching to the next tab ? | Vivaldi Forum](https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/16615/how-to-disable-auto-switching-to-the-next-tab/2)

> **[Ayespy](https://forum.vivaldi.net/user/ayespy)** [Moderator](https://forum.vivaldi.net/groups/global-moderators) [May 5, 2017, 10:20 PM](https://forum.vivaldi.net/post/135189) last edited by Ayespy May 5, 2017, 10:23 PM
>
> [@Deranox](https://forum.vivaldi.net/uid/96701): You can't right now. Rather, use one of the other options to open a background tab. 1) select "open link in new background tab" from the context menu (second choice), 2) use middle-click on the link with your mouse; 3) use Ctrl+leftclick on the link with your mouse, 4) designate a mouse gesture to open a background tab when you perform it over a link.

Answer (score 1):

The [**Force Background Tab**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/force-background-tab/gidlfommnbibbmegmgajdbikelkdcmcl?hl=en) extension will allow all links opened in new tabs to load in the background (not switch to it and make it active). [Force Background Tab GitHub page](https://github.com/monque/ChromeExtension-ForceBackgroundTab/)

Description:

> Normally, each click on a link that wants to open a new tab will ACTIVATE THE NEW TAB.
>   Now, after installing this extension, the new tab will be RUNNING IN THE BACKGROUND.