# Why is Firefox still switching to new tab when created? Didn't tick "When you open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately"

Tags: firefox

Please see GIF under [This is the website](https://www.originpc.com/landing/2019/watch-2-win-giveaway?gsr=OcA5g-ss7SZFidIF#enter) where I see this issue. I want stay on  current tab. Note I never ticked "When you open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately".

[image]

Comment: The page itself could be set to open in new tab. There's nothing you can really do to override that. Some browsers will hover the info at the bottom of the page, so you can see what the behaviour will be for any click or modifier method.

Comment: The fact that you have asked basically the same question 4 times for 4 different browsers would reinforce this. Ref: https://superuser.com/questions/1470585/how-can-chrome-not-automatically-switch-to-new-tab-when-new-tab-is-created & https://superuser.com/questions/1470598/how-can-edge-not-automatically-switch-to-new-tab-when-new-tab-is-created & https://superuser.com/questions/1470563/why-internet-explorer-still-switching-to-new-tab-when-created-didnt-tick-alwa

Comment: I can't test your specific website because it's throwing out some nasty cookies my browser is set to discard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

harrymc's answer didn't work. I musted toggle other setting in that link. I put star next to it in screen-shot beneath.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The HTML of the website is opening the link with the option of
[target=_blank](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)
which causes it to open in a new window or tab (according to browser settings).

You do not need such a complicated website to demonstrate this behavior.
This minimal [Tryit example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_a_target)
is already enough to demonstrate it.

In Firefox this behavior can be disabled by entering `about:config`
in the address bar, then setting `browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground` to `true`.

For more details see the Mozilla Support article
[Can I force a link to open in a non-active tab, instead of changing to that tab?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1066419)